# C++ Why is an uninitialized Vector's insert as fast as push_back and assignment?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, c++17

In an attempt to understand how Vectors behave, I coded the following three toy examples:

1. vector_using_assignment.cc:  Initialize a vector to 1,000,000 and assign its elements in a for loop

```
// 1. vector_using_assignment
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int N = *argv[1];
  std::vector<int> V(N);
  for (int i =0; i < N; i++) {
      V[i] = i;
  }  
}
$ g++ -O0 -std=c++17 vector_using_assignment.cc -o vector_using_assignment
$ time ./vector_using_assignment 1000000
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.001s
```

2. vector_using_push_back.cc: Create an empty vector and then assign its elements in a for loop using the push_back method

```
// 2. vector_using_push_back.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int N = *argv[1];
  std::vector<int> V;
  for (int i =0; i < N; i++) {
      V.push_back(i);
  }    
}
$ g++ -O0 -std=c++17 vector_using_push_back.cc -o vector_using_push_back
$ time ./vector_using_push_back 1000000
real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

3. vector_using_insert.cc Create an empty vector and then assign its elements in a for loop using the insert method

```
// 3. vector_using_insert.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int N = *argv[1];
  std::vector<int> V;
  for (int i =0; i < N; i++) {
  V.insert(V.begin(), N - i - 1);
  }
}
$ g++ -O0 -std=c++17 vector_using_insert.cc -o vector_using_insert
$ time ./vector_using_insert 1000000
  real  0m0.004s
  user  0m0.003s
  sys   0m0.001s
```

As you can see, all methods are exactly equal.  My understanding is that `push_back` is linear in complexity (when size < capacity).  This is clearly no the case in this example.  Shouldn't the `insert` method be linear also?

My guesses are that:

1. `c++17` is doing some optimization even though I turned off optimization?
2. My machine has 2 CPU's with I think 20 cores each, and 32G RAM, so this is making behave differently to what I am thinking?  I tried 100,000,000 but still saw no changes

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It could still optimize some, like remove code  that doesn't have any observable effect - which means it could optimize away everything in your programs. Also, your `N` will be far too small for the loop to even be noticed on a modern computer.

Comment: `int N = *argv[1];` is odd. Generally you'd want to convert the string to an int. I'd guess `N` is not at all what you might think. Print it out. It's probably 49.

Comment: Just looking casually, you are measuring much too small a time interval.  It would be more appropriate to run the test many times to amplify any differences in timings.  In theory, your test #1 has O(2N) memory traversal and a single allocation.  Your other two cases have potentially O(logN) allocations amortized to O(N) copies, so amounts to O(N) traversal.  Cache considerations may come into play, and as Ted suggests it is possible your code is optimized away because you didn't _do_ anything with the data.  Consider a step after the timing that averages the vector contents into a volatile.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You're guess was spot on.  N is 49.

Comment: Re: _"My understanding is that push_back is linear in complexity (when size < capacity)"_ -- in fact `push_back` is surprisingly _always_ constant time.  Read about the amortized time complexity of `std::vector::push_back`.  The `insert` method can also be constant in such cases, but _only_ when inserting at the end of the vector.  In general, insertion at the end is akin to `push_back`.  Insertion anywhere else is linear, and in your case, looping to insert at the beginning is polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

As expected, there was a bug in how I convert the stdin arg to int.  The correct way is:

```
int N = atoi(argv[1]);
std::cout << "N = " << N << std::endl;
```

Now I see some real differences:

```
$ time ./vector_using_push_back 1000000000
N = 1000000000

real    0m20.139s
user    0m16.437s
sys 0m3.701s

$ time ./vector_using_assignment 1000000000
N = 1000000000

real    0m7.530s
user    0m6.005s
sys 0m1.525s

$ time ./vector_using_insert 1000000000
N = 1000000000
# I gave up after a couple of min
```

Comment: Regarding your other question about the insert method being linear: note that you are inserting at the beginning which is not a linear operation for `std::vector`.  This would explain the excruciating performance (because your test is O(N^2)).  For fun, I knocked together a similar program (but did a linear operation for insertion) here: https://godbolt.org/z/naM35MPPf -- I also added a fourth test using the recommended approach of reserving storage before pushing a known quantity of data.  The performance of that is more closer to the naive initialization.

Comment: `atoi` returns `int`; there’s no need to cast the result.